# jQuery remove class that hides content

Tags: jquery

I have a div that 'overlays' on top of the main container using the position absolute within a relatively positioned container thing. I'm trying to get it so that when I click on a button, it appears by removing the `hide` class. It seemingly has no effect, even though in the console I get no errors (and `newThread` isn't hidden.)

```html
<div id='newThread' class='hide'>
    <form>
        <textarea></textarea>
    </form>
</div>
```

```css
 #container { position: relative; }

 #newThread { 
 position: absolute;
 top: 50px;
 background-color: rgba(239, 239, 239, 0.9);
 left: 50px; width: 600px;
 min-height: 480px; border-radius: 5px;
 box-shadow: 5px 2px 5px #888; 
 }

 .hide { display: none; }
```

```js
 $('#sidebar').html('<h1>Welcome to the forum!</h1><div class="container"><button class="btn btn-default" id="newThreadButton">New Topic</button><br /><button class="btn btn-default">Log out</button></div>');
 $('#sidebar').fadeIn();
 $('#newThreadButton').click(function() {
     $('#newThread').removeClass('hide');                       
 });
```

`alert($('#newThread').hasClass('hide'));` outputs `false`.

http://jsfiddle.net/YBqMn/

Comment: use `z-index` to ensure position of overlapping elements...

Comment: Any way you could make a fiddle?

Comment: A `z-index` of -1 does nothing either.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YBqMn/ The code goes through animations and ajax so it was sort of difficult to strip it down.

Comment: you have a position `absolute` in the `newThread` remove it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The animations are probabilly doing `style="display:none;"` on element. Try, instead of removing class hide, do `$(element).show();`

After seeing fiddle, you have `z-index: -1` on #newThread. Change that to `z-index: 2000` and you will see the overlay. (not sure if this is what you want)

I updated your fiddle : 
http://jsfiddle.net/YBqMn/1/

Comment: Sadly this logical answer didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You're assign function to element that doesn't exist on page. You can write into first line:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" onclick="$('#newThread').removeClass('hide')">
```

Answer (score 0):

THe element #NewThreadButton does not exist.

one alternative is

```
$('#newThread button, #newThread submit').click(function() {
     $('#newThread').removeClass('hide');                       
});
```

that will be triggered if you click any BUTTON or SUBMIT element inside the form.

make sure you have at least one BUTTON or SUBMIT inside the form.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was that I had put `newThread` in the same container that I was wiping upon the ajax call, and so that the element didn't exist when I updated the sidebar. I figured this out when it was outputting fine upon document load, but `undefined` when the sidebar animation started. I had to add a wrapper around the forms to separate that from the `newThread` div. I also had to remove `z-index: -1` as that was causing issues.